# iOS: UITableView in popover and seeing "double vision" effect

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm working on an iPad app and at some points, I need to show a popover with options for a user to pick from. For this, I use a UITableView in a UIPopoverController. The problem is that, on an iPad (not on the simulator), when scrolling the tableview, I get a sort of "double vision" effect, where it appears like two sets of of the list exist. One that is stationary, and one that scrolls up and down.

I construct the popover like this:

```
self.fClassTypeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.fClassTypeList removeAllObjects];

NSUInteger stringLength = 0;
(populate self.fClassTypeList, and set stringLength to the size of the longest entry)

[self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(stringLength * 15.0f, [self.fClassTypeList count] * 30)];

CGFloat tableBorderLeft = 5;
CGFloat tableBorderRight = 5;
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.size.width -= tableBorderLeft + tableBorderRight; // reduce the width of the table

self.fListOfItems = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.fListOfItems.delegate = self;
self.fListOfItems.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.fListOfItems];
```

I put in the viewDidLayoutSubviews(…) part of the view controller, maybe I should put it somewhere else? I am not sure why this happens on the actual machine, but not the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-viewDidLayoutSubviews` is a weird place to put allocations because that method can be called multiple times. So as far as your main issue goes, I believe you should move your allocations into the `-init` method, and move your layout code into your `-viewWillAppear` method.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.fClassTypeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        self.fListOfItems = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self.fListOfItems.delegate = self;
        self.fListOfItems.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:self.fListOfItems];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void )viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSUInteger stringLength = 0;

    CGFloat tableBorderLeft = 5;
    CGFloat tableBorderRight = 5;
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.size.width -= tableBorderLeft + tableBorderRight; // reduce the width of the table
    self.fListOfItems.frame = viewFrame;

    [self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(stringLength * 15.0f, [self.fClassTypeList count] * 30)];
}
```

This promotes better memory management.

As an added bonus, I would recommend you refactor the 
`[self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(stringLength * 15.0f, [self.fClassTypeList count] * 30)];` method into a setter method of `fClassTypeList`. Even better is to simply call `-viewWillAppear:` in that same setter method instead. This will promote good scalability as you (or someone else) continues to build upon this code later on.

It's a little confusing to see what exactly you're trying to accomplish in this code because it's so hardcoded so let me know if I'm missing the mark you're looking for (w/ an explanation why) and I'll make an edit.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will restructure my work. What I'm trying to accomplish is to make sure that the popover hugs the size of the contents.